# Managed Instance SQL Size (8TB General purpose) is per database or per SQL instance

Tags: azure, azure-sql-managed-instance

Need to know the database size limit for Azure SQL Managed Instance, is that per server or per database?.
I mean can I have 2 databases of 7TB each in one managed instance?

Answer (score 0):

The storage limit is at the instance (server) level. The maximum storage size for MI is 8TB so you would need to split these two 7 TB databases across 2 servers (instances).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-managed-instance-resource-limits#service-tier-characteristics

Comment: Thanks for the update. will I be able to query cross Managed instance server using the Linked server ?